# Blazor Controls the ChildContent property

Tags: c#, blazor

I want to control the properties of the component passed in the SButtonGroup's ChildContent. It is a delegate. How do I get the passed component and pass the parameters to the component?

[image: [HTML Snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j98wN.png)]

[image: [SButtonGroup Partial Class]()]

Comment: Hello, please use code instead of pictures

Comment: To pass data from `SButtonGroup` to each instance of `SButton` you need to create an object and cascade it from `SButtonGroup`.  As you haven't shown what you want to pass then ......  too Simple!